# What is your approach on sync two linux server in AWS

Tags: linux, rsync

I have the following:

- Linux Apache Server A = /var/www/webroot
- Linux Apache Server B = /var/www/webroot

How do you sync the two webroot Server A -> Server B in just one direction? If you are using rsync, what is the exact parameters do you used to sync any new files on webroot at Server A to B?

I would appreciate anyone to share on how do you approach this kind of system to your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Server A:

```
$ rsync -az --delete /var/www/webroot/ user@serverB:/var/www/webroot/
```

This assumes, of course, that you've created "user" on serverB and have configured key authentication. Those two steps are out of scope for this question, though, but can be easily researched in other Q&As on ServerFault.

Comment: also consider --delete to delete any files which are at serverB, but NOT on serverA.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that this is AWS, you might consider using EBS and volume snapshots.

(you can mount a volume at /var/www/webroot, take a snapshot, and then redeploy to other machines)

This bypasses any need for data copy, and should scale out faster to many nodes.